# Automated testing web page by macro and waiting for response from server

Tags: javascript, web, automated-tests

I am looking for a good program to test the web:
http://ffmama.azurewebsites.net/Home/About
There's a table and buttons to perform read and write.

 From the same table, you can enter data, the cell turns into a textarea and you can enter text to td.
The write operation sometimes take one second and sometimes 10 seconds.
It must be possible to synchronize the macro depending on the performance of the server, the js code I can add additional lines to synchronize.

Please advise how to choose the best software for testing web applications to:
- Work on different browsers,
- Synchronize their actions on the basis of confirmation from the server,
- Generate a report at the end of work.
- base on template macro

Thank you!
Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

You can use [selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/).

You will be able to write code in your preferred programming language 
and execute commands in chrome or any other browser.